# AngularJS array does not take \n

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

Following array defines the "About" of my app:

```
var aboutEntries = [
        { label: 'Name', value: apkDependencies.apkName },
        { label: 'Company', value: apkDependencies.apkCompany },
        { label: 'Version', value: apkDependencies.apkVersion },
        { label: "Apk's supported", value: apkDependencies.apkPackagearmv7},
        { label: "", value: apkDependencies.apkPackagex86},
        { label: 'Build Date', value: apkDependencies.apkDate }
    ]
```

However for the label Apk's supported it puts a line inbetween. Meaning it prints

```
xxxxarmv7.apk
-------------------
xxxxxx86.apk
```

I want to avoid the line it puts between the two apk names.
So to avoid that line I did as below but "\n" is not working. 
How do I make the \n work or how do I print it without a line between them?

```
var aboutEntries = [
        { label: 'Name', value: apkDependencies.apkName },
        { label: 'Company', value: apkDependencies.apkCompany },
        { label: 'Version', value: apkDependencies.apkVersion },
        { label: "Apk's supported", value: apkDependencies.apkPackagearmv7 + "\n" + apkDependencies.apkPackagex86},
        { label: 'Build Date', value: apkDependencies.apkDate }
    ]
```

Following is the HTML code I am using to create the template and later using ionicPopup() I am putting out the message:

```
    var template = ''
            aboutEntries.forEach(function (item) {
              template += '<ion-item>' +
                '<ion-label item-left>' + item.label + '</ion-label>' +
                '<ion-note item-right>' + item.value + '</ion-note>' +
              '</ion-item>'
            })

            template = '<ion-list>' + template + '</ion-list>'
            var alertPopup = $ionicPopup.alert({
              title: 'About CareBank Application',
              template: template
            });
```

Comment: Show us the rest of your code; the html for one, the css for two.

Comment: I just added the html, there is no CSS. Also both the array's are the same. Just for clarity I showed them as two instances. Thanks for the response.

Comment: Please correctly tag the question with all frameworks in use, because vanilla js is not what you are solely using.

Comment: It is solved all I had to do is replace "\n" by <br> and it works. My thought process was wrong the line break of the string was being ignored by the HTML which actually did the print part. Thanks @Daedalus when you asked for HTML code I realized it and took the hint. So this issue can be closed

Answer (score 0):

`\n` isn't valid HTML. Perhaps you need a `<br>` tag instead. Replace your `\n` with `<br>`.

Comment: Click the outlined checkmark under the down arrow to mark this question as solved.

Comment: Yes I did and it works and for some reason I cant click on the Answer. Please consider this as closed.